# Excel - getting a value based on the max value off another row in a Table

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a solution for a problem I'm facing in Excel. This is my table simplified:
Every sale has an unique ID, but more people can have contributed to a sale. the column "name" and "share of sales(%)" show how many people have contributed and what their percentage was.

| Sale_ID | Name | Share of sales(%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A | 100 |
| 2 | Person B | 100 |
| 3 | Person A | 30 |
| 3 | Person C | 70 |

Now I want to add a column to my table  that shows the name of the person that has the highest share of sales percentage per Sales_ID. Like this:

| Sale_ID | Name | Share of sales(%) | Highest sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person A | 100 | Person A |
| 2 | Person B | 100 | Person B |
| 3 | Person A | 30 | Person C |
| 3 | Person C | 70 | Person C |

So when multiple people have contributed the new column shows only the one with the highest value.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this on cell `D2`:

```
=LET(maxSales, MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,A2:A5), 
 INDEX(B2:B5, XMATCH(A2:A5&maxSales,A2:A5&C2:C5)))
```

or just removing the `LET` since `maxSales` is used only one time:

```
=INDEX(B2:B5, XMATCH(A2:A5&MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,A2:A5),A2:A5&C2:C5))
```

On cell `E2` I provided another solution via `MAP/XLOOKUP`:

```
=LET(maxSales, MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,A2:A5),
MAP(A2:A5, maxSales, LAMBDA(a,b, XLOOKUP(a&b, A2:A5&C2:C5, B2:B5))))
```

similarly without `LET`:

```
=MAP(A2:A5, MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,A2:A5), 
 LAMBDA(a,b, XLOOKUP(a&b, A2:A5&C2:C5, B2:B5)))
```

and here is the output:
[image: sample output]

### Explanation

The trick here is to identify the max share of sales per each group and this can be done via `MAXIFS(max_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`. The size and shape of the `max_range` and `criteria_rangeN` arguments must be the same.

```
MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,A2:A5)
```

it produces the following output:

| maxSales |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 100 |
| 70 |
| 70 |

`MAXIFS` will provide an output of the same size as `criteria1`, so it returns for each row the corresponding maximum sales for each **Sale_ID** column value.

It is the array version equivalent to the following formula expanding it down:

```
MAXIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,A2)
```

#### `INDEX/XMATCH` Solution

Having the array with the maximum **Shares of sales**, we just need to identify the row position via `XMATCH` to return the corresponding `B2:B5` cell via `INDEX`. We use concatenation (`&`) to consider more than one criteria to find as part of the `XMATCH` input arguments.

#### `MAP/XLOOKUP` Solution

We use `MAP` to find for each pair of values (`a`,`b`) per row, of the first two `MAP` input arguments where is the maximum value found for that group and returns the corresponding **Name** column value. In order to make a lookup based on an additional criteria we use concatenation (`&`) in `XLOOKUP` first two input arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, have solved it! I had to switch my Excel version, since the MAP function isn't available in every version yet or something. Might be handy to know for others.

Comment: @EmBL check my answer again I provided an alternative to `MAP` via `INDEX/XMATCH`